# E: Version '2.0.25' for 'mongodb-10gen' was not found while installing this specific version

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install version 2.0.25 for some testing work. I followed [this documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Here are the steps:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen

apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.0.25
```

But I get this error every time
**E: Version '2.0.25' for 'mongodb-10gen' was not found**

How do I install this specific version?

Comment: If you are definitely referring to the MongoDB server, there is no 2.0.25 release: the final release in the 2.0 series was 2.0.9. However, given the MongoDB 2.0 server series was first released in 2011 and EOL in March, 2013 I'd hope you are actually looking for a more modern version of MongoDB.

Comment: @Stennie you may want to convert your comment into an answer, because it is the answer.

Comment: @Stennie you're right about the mongo version. There is no 2.0.25.
But 2.0.2  was the version i was looking for. 

>>>> apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.0.2 <<<<

worked

Answer (score 1):

if anone lands here in future then follow these steps for installing OLDER versions ( 2.4 and earlier versions )

```
  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

        echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list

        sudo apt-get update

    apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.0.2
```

replace 2.0.2 with your required version.

for Versions 2.6 and above replace last step with this format

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=2.6.9 mongodb-org-server=2.6.9 mongodb-org-shell=2.6.9 mongodb-org-mongos=2.6.9 mongodb-org-tools=2.6.9
```

replace 2.6.9 with your mongo version ( only 2.6 and above )